# Separating different data from within a string

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have String vector that has data set look like below.

```
vector<string> result;

<index> | <Name> | <email> | <status>

    1|duleep|dfe@gamil.com|0
    2|dasun|dasun@da.com|0
    3|sampath|lkdf@dg.lk|1
    4|Nuwan|Kandyjkj@lkj.com|0
```

now i want to get separate vector data(Name, Index,Status) please suggest best way to do this using C++(how can i convert to string array[4][4]?)

Comment: What does your `data` `class` look like? Have you overloaded `operator >>()` for it?

Comment: If you want to tokenize the string then you can look for c++ stringstream

Comment: @Raghuram Are you thing it's best solution for my problem? Is there any way access simple like accessing array?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  What issues did you encounter?  Maybe http://tlzprgmr.wordpress.com/2008/04/22/using-boost-to-tokenize-strings/ will help you....

Comment: I have an offer but do you have to convert to string array[4][4]? Is it obligatory?

Comment: This is also very similar to [CSV parser in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1120140/78845) but using `|`s instead of `,`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example I came up with using [boost::tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html) (if you don't want to use boost, then sorry):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> v;
  v.push_back("1|duleep|dfe@gamil.com|0");
  v.push_back("2|dasun|dasun@da.com|0");
  v.push_back("3|sampath|lkdf@dg.lk|1");
  v.push_back("4|Nuwan|Kandyjkj@lkj.com|0");

  boost::char_separator<char> sep("|");
  std::vector<boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char>>> tokens;
  for (auto& s : v)
  {
    tokens.push_back({s, sep});
  }
}
```

If you want to use `std::string array[4][4]`, just iterate through the tokens and assign them to your array.

Here is another way without boost:

```
  for (auto& s : v)
  {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string token;
    while (std::getline(ss, token, '|'))
    {
        // Put token into your array here
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks your feed back Is there any way for get string array?(without use 3party library?)

Comment: @user881703: I added another way in my answer (but I didn't provide all the code).